# OS X Apache Error Log Entries - crls (Macports to Homebrew?)

Tags: apache, macports, homebrew, error-log

Yesterday I moved my local development environment from MacPorts over to Homebrew, and everything is running great. However I'm getting some odd apache log errors I've not come across before and wondered if anyone can help diagnose.

On tail'ing the error_log, they seem to happen every 10-15 seconds when general web browsing in chrome:

```
[Thu Apr 26 14:19:41 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Users/username/Sites/pca3.crl
[Thu Apr 26 14:20:04 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Users/username/Sites/ThawtePremiumServerCA.crl
[Thu Apr 26 14:22:02 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Users/username/Sites/crls
[Thu Apr 26 14:23:48 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Users/username/Sites/SVRSecureG3.cer
[Thu Apr 26 14:23:49 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /Users/username/Sites/SVRSecureG3.crl
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I have this problem too on Mac OS X Lion. I'm also running Charles Web Debugging Proxy. Are you running Charles too?

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked for me!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431512/no-mapping-found-for-crls-secureca-crl

Comment: Nope, not running Charles...