# No mapping found for [/crls/secureca.crl]

Tags: ssl-certificate, hosts, verisign, ipfw

This is what appears many times in console of Jetty local webserver when testing J2EE Spring app.

```
2012-05-03 14:28:14,716 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound]
- <No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/crls/secureca.crl] 
in DispatcherServlet with name 'DefaultServlet'>
```

I've setup my localhost (OSX) like this:

```
sudo ipfw add 100 fwd 127.0.0.1,8080 tcp from any to any 80 in
```

To forward all requests to localhost/127.0.0.1 from :80 to :8080

Does anybody know if this is severe bug/warning and how to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My mistake, I got (and only god knows why) in `/private/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 crl.verisign.com
127.0.0.1 crl.geotrust.com
```

So if anybody encounters the same issue, simply check your **hosts file** for `crl, verisign, geotrust` keywords and disable or delete matching lines.

- Note that **commenting in hosts file** works like this

  - `#127.0.0.1 crl.geotrust.com`

Comment: hmm, I didn't have that in hosts

Comment: @DmitryKharlamov Probably some other mapping for CA servers. Try to post dump of your hosts on pastebin and here, I can try to help you.

Comment: sorry, I did find something similar in my hosts as I was about to send it to you. As soon as I've removed the records it solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I meet this problem too, but I can't find crl.geotrust.com in my hosts file(/etc/hosts -> /private/etc/hosts). Hope to get some help.

Comment: @Lynn if it is caused by settings of your computer, try looking up something similar, whatever starting with `crl`, or hostname matching any CA keywords. easiest way is to remove any non-default directive from your hosts file and clear dns cache.

Comment: This is about Adobe Creative Suite activation & license check stuff. I've ended up here with the same issue.